# implementation of start/stop/pause using QThread in qt

Tags: qt, qthread

I am new to qt. I have an example that uses QThreads to perform a factorial calculations, with gui I should be able to start/stop/pause the calculation. I can start the application with defining the logic in run method as shown below.

```
#ifndef FACTORIALCALCULATOR_H
#define FACTORIALCALCULATOR_H

#include <QThread>

class FactorialCalculator : public QThread
{
public:
    FactorialCalculator();
    int inputNumber;
    long resultFactorial;

private:
    virtual void run();
    long calculateFactorial(int input);

};

#endif // FACTORIALCALCULATOR_H


#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "factorialcalculator.h";
#include "erathosthenesprimenumbercalculator.h";

FactorialCalculator factorialCalculator;
bool isSuspend = false;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    factorialCalculator.inputNumber = ui->lineEditFactorial->text().toInt();
    ui->resultFactorial->setText(QString(" %1 ").arg(factorialCalculator.resultFactorial));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_startFactorial_clicked()
{

    factorialCalculator.inputNumber = ui->lineEditFactorial->text().toInt();
    factorialCalculator.start();
    ui->resultFactorial->setText(QString(" %1 ").arg(factorialCalculator.resultFactorial));


}


    #include "factorialcalculator.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>


bool isRunning =false;

FactorialCalculator::FactorialCalculator()
{

}

void FactorialCalculator::run()
{

//    calculateFactorial(inputNumber);
    qDebug() << resultFactorial;
//   FactorialCalculator().sleep(2000);
    
    
}

long FactorialCalculator::calculateFactorial(int input)
{
    int n = input;
        unsigned long long factorial = 1;

//        qDebug() << "Enter a positive integer: ";
//        cin >> n;

        if (n < 0)
            qDebug() << "Error! Factorial of a negative number doesn't exist.";
        else {
            for(int i = 1; i <=n; ++i) {
                factorial *= i;
            }
            qDebug() << "Factorial of " << n << " = " << factorial;
        }
        FactorialCalculator().sleep(2000);
        resultFactorial = factorial;
        return factorial;
}
```

But I need to implement the pause and stop fucntionality. How can I do this, any pseudo code will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Create `pauseResumeCalculation` slot inside `FactorialCalculator` class, add bool member variable `isRunning` representing state of calculation, toggle its value inside slot `pauseResumeCalculation`, run calculation inside `run()` as a loop and periodically call `qApp->processEvents()` and check value of `isRunning` and according to value do sleep or calculation. Add slot `stopCalculation` and variable `stopRequested`, check its value inside `run()` loop and exit if it is set to true. Create signals inside main thread object and connect them to `pauseResumeCalculation` and `stopCalculation`.

Comment: Whenever I try to run the above program I get resultFactorial  variable as zero in the mainwindow.cpp?

Comment: You get initial value of variable because calculation isn't finished yet. To pass result to `MainWindow` add signal to `FactorialCalculator` connect in to slot in `MainWindow` and emit it when calculation is complete.

Comment: Could you please help with some example code